# using PDAcroForm to edit pdf but getting null while accessing default resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pdf

I am using PDAcroForm to update pdf in java but when I am trying to access default resources getting null from this method getDefaultResources.

Comment: Which PDF library are you using? And might that `null` simply be adequate for the PDF in question?

Comment: using PDFParser  and from PDResources getDefaultResources() getting null because of that not able to access getFonts() method.

Comment: You may want to [edit] your question to include that information. I cannot help as I don't know a *PDFParser* library.